# Google Custom Login UI Button - swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

I have managed to make a Google Login Button working. However, it is assigning the button image automatically from the SDK and it is not customisable (as it is not getting created on Storyboard).

How to create Google login custom button?

Answer (score 1):

Take your own custom button and inside its action, just write the line

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
```

Leave all other delegate methods as it is.

Comment: It's helpful if you apply the code format to your line: `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()`
I would do it as an edit, but can't as it is less than 6 characters. Please follow [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) to find out how to code format